# how to transform columns of a data frame according to the values in a vector in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to normalize some columns on a data frame so they have the same mean. The solution I am now implementing, even though it works, feels like there is a simpler way of doing this.

```
# we make a copy of women
w = women
# print out the col Means
colMeans(women)
height   weight 
65.0000 136.7333
# create a vector of factors to normalize with
factor = colMeans(women)/colMeans(women)[1]
# normalize the copy of women that we previously made
for(i in 1:length(factor)){w[,i] <- w[,i] / factor[i]}
#We achieved our goal to have same means in the columns
colMeans(w)
height weight 
65     65
```

I can come up with the same thing easily ussing `apply` **but** is there something easier like just doing `women/factor` and get the correct answer?
By the way, what does `women/factor` actually doing? as doing:

```
colMeans(women/factor)
height   weight  
49.08646 98.40094
```

Is not the same result.

Comment: have you tried "scale" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `mapply` too

```
colMeans(mapply("/", w, factor))
```

Re your question re what does `women/factor` do, so `women` is a `data.frame` with two columns, while `factor` is numeric vector of length two. So when you do `women/factor`, R takes each entry of `women` (i.e. `women[i,j]`) and divides it once by `factor[1]` and then `factor[2]`. Because factor is shorter in length than `women`, R rolls `factor` over and over again. 
You can see, for example, that every second entry of `women[, 1]/factor` equals to every second entry of `women[, 1]` (because `factor[1]` equals to 1)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is using `sweep`. By default this function subtracts a summary statistic from each row, but you can also specify a different function to perform. In this case a division:

```
colMeans(sweep(women, 2, factor, '/'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
rowMeans(t(women)/factor)
#height weight 
#65     65
```

Regarding your question:

`I can come up with the same thing easily ussing apply but is there something easier like just doing women/factor and get the correct answer? By the way, what does women/factor actually doing?`

```
women/factor ## is similar to

unlist(women)/rep(factor,nrow(women))
```

What you need is:

```
unlist(women)/rep(factor, each=nrow(women))
```

or

```
women/rep(factor, each=nrow(women))
```

In my solution, I didn't use `rep` because `factor` gets recycled as needed.

```
t(women) ##matrix

as.vector(t(women))/factor #will give same result as above
```

or just

```
t(women)/factor #preserve the dimensions for ?rowMeans
```

In short, column wise operations are happening here.